# liveness probes for manually created Endpoints

Tags: kubernetes

Is this a thing?

I have some legacy services which will never run in Kubernetes that I currently make available to my cluster by defining a service and manually uploading an endpoints object.

However, the service is horizontally sharded and we often need to restart one of the endpoints. My google-fu might be weak, but i can't figure out if Kubernetes is clever enough to prevent the Service from repeatedly trying the dead endpoint?

The ideal behavior is that the proxy should detect the outage, mark the endpoint as failed, and at some point when the endpoint comes back re-admit it into the full list of working endpoints.

BTW, I understand that at present, liveness probes are HTTP only. This would need to be a TCP probe because it's a replicated database service that doesn't grok HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the design is for the thing managing the endpoint addresses to add/remove them based on liveness. For services backed by pods, the pod IPs are added to endpoints based on the pod's readiness check. If a pod's liveness check fails, it is deleted and its IP removed from the endpoint.

If you are manually managing endpoint addresses, the burden is currently on you (or your external health checker) to maintain the addresses/notReadyAddresses in the endpoint.

Comment: Makes sense from a design perspective. Would be even better if there were a tool for manually managing endpoints that gives you a nice framework and hooks for checking manually configured Endpoints. Any such thing out there? Thanks for the answer.